# How do I use SASS in IBM MobileFirst project?

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I have been engaged in developing IBM MobileFirst + Ionic applications for the last few months, but I still couldn't figure out a way to use SASS. How I managed till date is, I will have a static Ionic project with SASS setup and I re-use/copy-paste the HTML and CSS from this static `www` folder to actual MobileFirst project `common` folder.

Is there a better way around, like to have a node + gulp setup on the MobileFirst project?

**NB:** I'm using IBM MobileFirst 7.0.0

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hybrid apps in v7.0, you use Eclipse. This makes things more complicated. In Eclipse you can use Ant scripts to alter the generated folder with anything you may need. Perhaps the Ant script could execute whatever it is that you need.

You can see an Ant script integration example in Studio, here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/

This will be easier for you in v7.1, where you can create "pure Cordova" apps using the command line, thus your integration points with other tools such as Node.js and gulp is much more natural, and more feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. From v7.0 to V7.1 is quite a decision to make because the MFP server is compatible with v7.0 (thats what I'm told).